# How do I create a BufferedImage from array containing pixels?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, pixel

I get the pixels from `BufferedImage` using the method `getRGB()`. The pixels are stored in array called `data[]`. After some manipulation on data array, I need to create a `BufferedImage` again so that I can pass it to a module which will display the modified image, from this data array, but I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Then set the pixels again.

```
bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, your_value);
```

<sub>PS: as stated in the comments, please use the answer from @TacticalCoder</sub>

Comment: You shouldn't loop through a whole image and set one bit at a time.  You should copy the whole buffer in one go.

Comment: this is a terrible way to set all the pixels in a bufferedimage and should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26):

> I get the pixels from the BufferedImage using the method getRGB(). The
>   pixels are stored in array called data[].

Note that this can possibly be terribly slow. If your BufferedImage supports it, you may want to instead access the underlying *int[]* and directly copy/read the pixels from there.

For example, to fastly copy your *data[]* into the underlying *int[]* of a new BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage( w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
final int[] a = ( (DataBufferInt) res.getRaster().getDataBuffer() ).getData();
System.arraycopy(data, 0, a, 0, data.length);
```

Of course you want to make sure that your *data[]* contains pixels in the same representation as your BufferedImage (ARGB in this example).

Comment: This is the better answer. I can't think of any situation in which setRGB is an optimal solution for anything.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your code: do you mean `bi.getRaster` instead of `res.getRaster`?

Comment: @manguy I don't think their answer works, I tried it. I think it is because they made an array using the BufferedImage data, but the array doesn't actually point to the BufferedImage. It is just a new reference that was created.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the RGB (int) values for the pixels in the new image using the setRGB methods.

Comment: how do i create the bufferedimage??