# difficulty converting an array to a bufferedimage in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I want to manipulate an image on a pixel by pixel basis in Java so I have set up a one dimensional list with my colours in it. I then convert this to a buffered image, but the pixels were all wrong.

So I've stripped it down to the absolute basics below. To my mind this ought to give a square with the left half blue and the right have black. Instead it gives blue and black diagonal stripes. Any ideas about what is going on please?

```
   private void create(){
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;
        int blue;
        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        int index = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
              if (x<50) {blue = 255;} 
              else blue=0;
              pix[index++] =  blue;
            }
        }
       image = new BufferedImage(100,100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       image.setRGB(0, 0, 100, 100, pix, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Check this, maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396159/how-do-i-create-a-bufferedimage-from-array-containing-pixels

Answer (score 0):

**You got the stride variable wrong.** This line:

```
image.setRGB(0, 0, 100, 100, pix, 0, 1);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
image.setRGB(0, 0, 100, 100, pix, 0, 100);
```

*There are a few small changes that could improve readability, but you can deal with those. The change above will fix the problem you asked about.*

Comment: Why is 1 the wrong answer and 100 the correct answer?

Comment: The stride variable controls how many elements there are in the array per row.  Why?

Comment: I was curious about what it meant.